# Vim E488 trailing characters but I don't see any trailing characters in file

Tags: bash, vim

Im opening the vimrc file with the following command `vim ~/.bash_profile`. Here's the error message and also the vim file contents. I actually get this error when ever I open any file with VIM.

```
Error detected while processing /Users/yako/.vimrc:
line    3:
E488: Trailing characters
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

.vimrc file

```
"Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags() ” generate helptags for everything in ‘runtimepath’
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote character used for comments is `"` (ASCII value 0x22 -- quotation mark), but you are using a character that looks similar, but is not the same: `”` (Unicode value 0x201d -- right double quotation mark)

Replace the character and it will work.

Comment: Yes you're right. I updated the question with the actual file

Comment: @DanielJacobson - Answer revised